# Does modern physics contradict transubstantiation?

Tags: catholicism, science, transubstantiation, metaphysics

According to modern physics, all physical things are reducible to atoms, and that's all they are.

In the doctrine of transubstantiation, the piece of bread's substance is transformed into Jesus, while its accidents remain the bread.  If the accidents are the atoms, then this implies there is more to the bread, i.e. its 'substance', than just the atoms, and this substance is changed.  If this is true, then is modern physics wrong, and there is something more to what bread is than just the atoms it is made of?  Additionally, what is this 'more' thing if we were to remove all the atoms from the bread, what would be left that provides the substance of the bread?  Alternatively, if the atoms constitute the entirety of the bread, then what changes about the bread during the Eucharist?

UPDATE: I've asked a [related question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/3106/where-does-aristotles-posterior-analytics-disagree-with-modern-philosophy-of-sc) in the philosophy stackexchange.  I'm not sure if I should close this question in the Christianity SE, since it has a couple answers.

Comment: When you build a table with wooden legs, does the transformation of the tree into part of a table violate the laws of physics?

Comment: @RayButterworth are you saying the "substance" is the shape of the bread?  The shape of the wafer doesn't appear to change during the Eucharist ceremony.

Comment: Transubstantiation was never about physics, but metaphysics.

Comment: @curiousdannii are you saying that the wafer consists of more than just atoms?  The doctrine of transubstantiation seems to imply there is something extra in the wafer called a 'substance': before the transubstantiation the 'substance' is 'wafer' and afterwards it is 'Jesus'.  Physics, on the other hand, say all physical objects are just atoms, there is no extra 'substance' to things.  These two positions appear to be in contradiction to each other.

Comment: The substance isn't the atoms, that's the accidents. Physics can't tell you that something non physical doesn't exist though.

Comment: A sort of converse to your question: "[Is transubstantiation faithfully Aristotelian?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/21677/2014)"

Comment: Perhaps someone can turn “[Hugon & Duhem on Hylemorphism & Modern Science](https://groups.google.com/g/quaestionesdisputatae/c/u_jIp2hebR0/m/4pFGb45VZCoJ?pli=1),” _Quæstiones Disputatæ: The Ite Ad Thomam Forum_, January 4, 2013, into a full answer.

Comment: @Geremia that forum posts sounds very interesting, as it seems to be saying that somehow modern physics retains a notion of substance.  I confess I don't really understand it!  But, if it could be made understandable, I believe it would answer my question.

Comment: @curiousdannii if we take away all the atoms from a physical object, or wavefunctions, or quarks, or whatever smallest physical unit there is, what is left?  If nothing, then the object reduces to just those physical units, they are not accidents, and 'substance' is just an empty label.  In which case, modern physics does contradict the Aristotelian concept of substance, as well as transubstantiation.  The only way to avoid this problem is if modern physics is wrong, and physical objects cannot be reduced to a composition of physical elements.

Comment: @yters Your question might more properly belong on https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ or https://hsm.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: It's nothing to do with "modern physics". People didn't think 200 years ago that transforming water into wine or bread into flesh was a perfectly normal thing to happen. They knew it could only be done by a miracle of divine power. "Modern physics" isn't telling us anything different.

Comment: @DJClayworth modern physics says all physical things can be reduced to their smallest physical components.  Once all those components are removed, then nothing remains of the object.  If that is true, then nothing about the object can change besides the physical components.  Transubstantiation says all the physical components stay the same, but the object itself changes.  However, if nothing about the object can change besides the physical components, and all the components stay the same, then the bread must remain bread, and transubstantiation cannot happen.

Comment: The assumption that an object is defined *only* by its physical components is a philosophical one, not a scientific one. Physics does indeed deal with only the material components of objects, but the assumption that that is all there is is the philosophy of materialism, not a conclusion of science. For example, if I have a historical artifact, say "the pen used to write the Declaration of Independence", and I create a pen that is identical down to the last atom, is that "the pen used to write the Declaration of Independence"?

Comment: @DJClayworth "use to write the DoI" is a label we give to the object, nothing inherent in the object.  If we change the label of an object, nothing changes about the object itself.  Transubstantiation states something inherent to the object changes.  The object really becomes Jesus himself, and hence there are lots of safeguards around treatment of the object during the Eucharistic ceremony.  Also, that's the reason why Catholics worship the object during Eucharistic adoration, because we believe the object really is God.  OTOH, physics claims nothing remains once all the lego bricks are gone.

Comment: Your statement is a philosophical statement in itself. You say "It's just a label we give the object", but I can't just go and label any pen "the pen used to write the DoI". If I say "That's the pen used to write the DoI" then that's either true or false, depending on which pen it is. It's an attribute of the object that I can't change by just "applying a label". Obviously if you adhere to the philosophy of materialism then you believe your statement about labels, but whether you believe it or not is a philosophical issue, not a physics issue.

Comment: @DJClayworth sure, some labels are not arbitrary, and cannot be changed willy nilly.  But they are still labels.  On the other hand, an apple is red because that's a property of the apple itself, not because it's the apple that was perceived by someone to be red.  Same with a Eucharistic host.  It's Jesus regardless of anybody thinks about the host. And sure, some philosophies say everything is a label, some say nothing is a label, and some say a bit of both.  Last option seems sensible, but modern physics implausibly says all non legos are labels.  Anyhoo, I've gone and asked this in philo SE

Comment: @yters Good, because that was exactly my point.

Answer (score 1):

> Does modern physics contradict transubstantiation?

No. Why? Well, because...

> According to modern physics, all physical things are reducible to atoms, and that's all they are.

...this is a *philosophical assumption* (commonly known as Philosophical Materialism) that cannot be proven scientifically. And, according to many Christians and even a number of scientists, it's wrong. Note that this assumption also a priori excludes God. Therefore, if God exists (and there is every reason to believe He does), then this assertion is false. Indeed, if consciousness cannot be reduced to material causes (as we have thus far failed to do), it is false.

So your question is based entirely on a specious assumption.

Noow, if your definition of "modern physics" *is* "materialism" (which, sadly, is the case for a great many "scientists"), then yes, it contradicts transubstantiation. But it does so by definition *and by philosophy*, not by evidence.

Comment: I think it is a bit more complicated.  Modern physics says that all physical objects are just a collection of some smallest physical unit: atoms, quantum wavefunctions, etc.  If correct, then if we remove all those smallest units, there would be nothing left of the physical object.  On the other hand, if the theory of substances is correct, then even with all those smallest units removed, something would remain of the physical object which we call the substance.  So, this is more than just a philosophical assumption, since it has physical ramifications.

Comment: @yters, correct in the sense that either hypothesis has non-physical consequences if correct. But that wasn't what I said; the *assertion* that there is nothing non-material is philosophical. It is justified on philosophical grounds, not on evidentiary grounds. Many would say the evidence is *against* that hypothesis.

Comment: I still think there are potentially evidentiary grounds one way or another.  Say the substance view was correct.  The substance can still do something.  Take the Eucharist.  The substance is supposed to be an efficient cause, and remove venial sins from the consumer who is in a state of grace.  Additionally, only transubstantiated hosts are capable of miraculously transforming into the accidents of Jesus flesh and blood, supposedly complete with Jesus' DNA.  Not to say any of that is true, but just to make the point that the theory of substances could have testable ramifications.

Comment: @yters, "DNA"? — [Compendium of the Catechism of the Catholic Church](https://www.vatican.va/archive/compendium_ccc/documents/archive_2005_compendium-ccc_en.html#:~:text=283.%20What%20is%20the%20meaning%20of%20transubstantiation) says "*the outward characteristics of bread and wine, that is the “eucharistic species”, remain unaltered*".  I.e. there is no detectable physical change in the bread or wine.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a bit of literature on this subject. One approach is to admit that the Aristotelian categories adopted by the Church to describe transubstantiation do seem to contradict Newtonian physics, but Quantum physics has rendered the debate moot. Father Michael Kelly, the Jesuit CEO of the Asian Catholic news agency UCA News [writes](https://www.firstthings.com/blogs/firstthoughts/2010/05/does-quantum-physics-render-transubstantiation-meaningless):

> Regrettably, all too frequently, the only Presence focused on is
> Christ’s presence in the elements of bread and wine. Inadequately
> described as the change of the ‘substance’ (not the ‘accidents’) of
> bread and wine into the body and blood of Christ, the mystery of the
> real presence of Christ in the Eucharist carries the intellectual
> baggage of a physics no one accepts. Aristotelian physics makes such
> nice, however implausible and now unintelligible, distinctions. They
> are meaningless in the post-Newtonian world of quantum physics, which
> is the scientific context we live in today.

[Deacon Steven D. Greydanus](https://www.ncregister.com/blog/tesseracts-wormholes-quantum-physics-and-the-eucharist) goes a step further:

> A tesseract or wormhole warps space-time to bridge the distance
> between two locations that are far apart within four-dimensional
> space. The Eucharist does something similar, except that instead of
> two spatial locations, it bridges the infinite distance between Earth
> and Heaven; what it makes present is not the other side of the galaxy,
> but Christ in Heaven

However, Deacon Greydanus also warns:

> Science reveals a world that exceeds the bounds of human experience,
> comprehension, and imagination. We cannot form an accurate imaginative
> picture of the world of quantum mechanics, any more than we can form
> an accurate imaginative picture of the body and blood of Christ being
> present under the appearances of bread and wine. Yet quantum theory
> allows us to make true statements about the unimaginable world of
> quantum physics and to avoid certain false ideas — and theology does
> something similar in regard to mysteries of faith.

In the end, for those who believe in the Real Presence, it is not a question of one contradicting each other. It has always been been a Mystery of Faith. On the other hand, who knows if the day is coming when Quantum physics well enable the faithful to "know," as well as to "believe."

Comment: Note, my question is more general than just transubstantiation.  The doctrine presumes the prior concept of 'substance', which seems to be entirely absent from modern physics.  Modern physics says a physical object is entirely reducible to the lowest level physical thing, whether that be atoms or quantum waveforms.  Substituting the quantum waveforms for the atoms, I would still have the same question.  Is the wafer just the waveforms, and do those waveforms somehow change during transubstantiation?  Or is there still an extra thing besides the waveforms called 'substance' that the wafer has?

Comment: Yes... the concept of substance is central in this.

Comment: In that case, I think you are basically saying our understanding of quantum physics is so little at this point that there is room for Aristotelian substances to play a role?  I don't think that quite makes sense, because while it's hard to conceptualize quantum physics, it still seems to be clear that all physical things reduce to 'wavefunctions', which are a bunch of individual things and not a composite 'substance'.  So, quantum physics still contradicts Aristotelianism and transubstantiation.

Comment: My answer is based on a working knowledge of theology, not physics. Sorry. but I have to plead ignorance here.

Answer (score 0):

A big cause for confusion is the traditional use of the words "substance" and "accident", whose common English meanings are opposite to how they are used when describing transubstantiation.

The official terms are:

- "substance": what is the essential quality of the object.
- "accident": what just happens to be an irrelevant attribute of the object.

Here, the word "substance" does *not* mean what the object is made out of.
A better word would be "essence" (i.e. what is essential).

Consider that, after being transformed, what is essential is that the object is now a leg, a part of a table, and what is accident is that it happens to be made of wood.
It would still be a leg even if it were made of plastic or metal.

Similarly in transubstantiation, after being transformed, what is essential is that the object is now part of Christ's body, and what is accident is that it happens to be made of bread.

Just as physics has nothing to say about the transformation of a tree into part of a table, it also has nothing to say about the transformation of a piece of bread into part of Christ.

Transubstantiation is entirely spiritual, not physical, so no laws of physics are involved.

Comment: "_transformation of a piece of bread into part of Christ_" No. Transubstantiation replaces the substance of bread with that of Christ Himself, whole and entire.

Comment: "_Transubstantiation is entirely spiritual, not physical, so no laws of physics are involved._" No. Christ is truly, really, physically present, in his Body, Blood, Soul, and Divinity.

Comment: @Geremia says "*replaces the substance of bread … whole and entire*". Are you using "substance" in the modern sense of what something is physically made of?  If so, are you saying that after the transformation the host is safe to consume by people with celiac disease?

Comment: @RayButterworth would Aristotle say 'table' is the substance of the thing that has the wooden legs?  I think he instead says 'table' is an artificial thing, not a substance.  It gets back to my original question, since the issue is modern physics says a physical thing is just a composite of a bunch of units.  If true, then the essence of the physical thing is just the collection of those units.  However, bread is not just water and flour, since it transforms into first dough, and when heated it hardens into bread.  Maybe baking contradicts modern physics.

Comment: @RayButterworth "what something is made of" is its [matter](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34787) ([material cause](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/34466/2014)). A [substance](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=36683) is something that exists in itself (like an apple). An [accident](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=31614) is something that exists in another (like redness in a red apple).

Comment: @yters asks "*would Aristotle say 'table' is the substance of the thing*". It's best to avoid the word "substance".  To normal people, the table is made of a substance such as wood or plastic or metal. To theologians, for a table "tableness" is the substance, and wood is the accident. So, regardless of the language or words, what makes a table a table is the fact that it *is* a table (a stable flat surface); being a table is its essential nature (or theological substance). It's accidental nature is the material substance that it is made of (or theological accident).

Comment: @yters says "*the essence of the physical thing is just the collection of those units*". A dog's essence (substance) is dog, and a cat's is cat, even though both are made out of the same physical material (accident). If you see two ornaments or paintings you might say "that's a dog and that's a cat", even though what they are physically made of is neither.  Essence has nothing to do with what something is made of, it has to do with what essentially makes it what it is. A table and a chair are essentially different, even though physically they are identical 100% wood.

Comment: What you are describing sounds more like Platonic forms.  Aristotle's theory of forms is different, intentionally so, since he didn't believe in a separate Platonic realm of forms.  One interesting example is Aristotle's idea of the soul, which is a form that can contain forms.  So, the soul is a kind of form that takes action in the world.  For Aristotle, the form is not an abstract idea we ascribe to a physical thing, but something that inheres in the physical thing itself.  The form may or may not be the same as an Aristotelean substance, I'm not well versed enough in Aristotelianism.

Answer (score 0):

NO, modern Physics restricts itself to the physical because it must. To say that that is all there is is to go beyond Physics.
Transubstantiation is in no way a basis for Catholic teaching, but rather the opposite. It is showing that the Faith is not irrational by showing that it does not violate mainstream metaphysics.

The brilliant convert Catholic philosopher G E M Anscombe might put you at ease by
this piece was written about her little child and the Eucharist
https://archive.secondspring.co.uk/articles/anscombe.htm

Comment: If I could understand it, maybe it'd put me at ease!  Too brilliant for my mind.  At any rate, I'm not uneasy.  It does seem transubstantiation contradicts modern physics, which means modern physics is wrong.